# Magento 2 How to disable category attribute on condition?

Tags: magento, categories, magento2, backend, magento-2.3

Magento 2 How to disable category attribute-based on condition.

In my example,

I have to enable the category attribute only for the L2 category and at another category, it should be disabled.

Comment: Post the same on StackExchange also.

Answer (score 3):

In my example, I have to enable the custom category attribute only for the L2 category and on another category level, it should be disabled.

1. In your custom di.xml file add this code to extend Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\DataProvider.php

   `<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\DataProvider" type="xyz\abc\Model\Notification\DataProvider" />`
2. After you extend the `Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\DataProvider.php` file now create `xyz\abc\Model\Notification\DataProvider.php` file in your custom module, in which we call the `getData()` function for

`

```
public function getData() {    
           if (isset($this->loadedData)) {    
            return $this->loadedData;    
        }
        $category = $this->getCurrentCategory();

        if ($category) {
            $categoryLevel = $category->getLevel();
            $categoryData = $category->getData();
            $categoryData = $this->addUseConfigSettings($categoryData);
            $categoryData = $this->filterFields($categoryData);
            $categoryData = $this->convertValues($category, $categoryData);

            $this->loadedData[$category->getId()] = $categoryData;
//Customization Started
            if( $categoryLevel == 2 )  
                $this->loadedData[$category->getId()]['do_we_hide_it'] = false;
            else
                $this->loadedData[$category->getId()]['do_we_hide_it'] = true;
//Customization ended
        }
        return $this->loadedData;
}
```

`

In the above code, I have done the customization to get the flag (do_we_hide_it) value so then we can use this flag in our category_form.xml to enable/disable the category attribute.

Note: Please copy function convertValues($category, $categoryData) from `Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\DataProvider.php` into `xyz\abc\Model\Notification\DataProvider.php` because this function is private so won't able to extend the function.

3. So now go on your `category_form.xml (path: xyz/abx/view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml)` and add this code in your custom category attribute.

`

```
<field name="your_custom_attibute_name">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
       ........
    </argument>
<!-- Customization Started -->
    <settings>
        <imports>
            <link name="disabled">${ $.provider}:data.do_we_hide_it</link>
        </imports>
    </settings>
<!-- Customization ended -->
</field>
```

`

4. php bin/magento cache:flush
5. Done

Comment: I very much appreciated your excellent work!  Keep up the good work!